# deepspeech training audio file length

Tags: wav, transcription, mozilla-deepspeech

Is it compulsory to have training and inferring audio file length equal to 5 seconds?
I have this questions because I have a large amount of training data with audio(every audio more than 30 seconds) and respective transcripts. If I can’t use this data as it is for training, then I need to chunk the audio files( which I can do easily with some python script) but I am finding it difficult to chunk the transcript for the respective chunked audio files. I am doing it manually for now, but is there any way to automate it?

Any suggestions?

Thank you:)

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: No.. I created chunks of 5 second each audio file. I could write scripts to automate a few procedures according to my scenario.